# ExpressJS Server Goes Offline Every Night - 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, nginx

I have a website with Nginx installed as a reserve proxy for an ExpressJS server (proxies to port 3001). This uses Node and ReactJS for my frontend application.

This is simply a testing website currently, and isn't known or used by any users. I have this installed on a Digital Ocean Droplet with Ubuntu.

Every morning when I wake up, I load my website and see `502 Bad Gateway`. The problem is, I don't know how to find out how this happened. I have PM2 installed which should automatically restart my ExpressJS server but it hasn't done so, and when I run `pm2 list`, my application is still showing `online`:

[image]

When I run `pm2 logs`, I get the following error (I am running this as an Administrator):

[image]

So I'll run `pm2 restart all` to restart the app, but then I don't see any crash information. However on this occasion when taking this screenshot, there were a couple of unusual requests. `/robots.txt`, `/sitemap.xml` and `/.well-known/security.txt`, but nothing indicating a crash:

[image]

When I look at my Nginx `error.log` file, all I can see is the following:

[image]

There is, however, something obscure within my `access.log` (`[09/Oct/2018:06:33:19 +0000]`) but I have no idea what this means:

[image]

If I run `curl localhost:3001` whilst the server is offline, I will receive a connection error message. This works fine after I run `pm2 restart all`.

I'm completely stuck with this and even the smallest bit of help would be appreciated greatly, even if it's just to tell me I'm barking up the wrong tree completely and need to look elsewhere - thank you.

Comment: Get a look to the Digital Ocean monitoring dashboard, do you see any peak of CPU/Mem?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I see something - https://imgur.com/GVsqIIH

Comment: The 6 am peak could be the result of a huge http request, as the one you see from the access log. Do you have any extra-security measure installed on your Ubuntu? Like selinux?

Comment: Something goes wrong in your node.js application. It is very likely to be logged inside the pm2 logs. Thanks for updating the question with longer pm2 logs contents than the last 15 lines presently shared. You may want to use `--lines` flag, e.g. `pm2 logs --lines 1000`.

Comment: @AndreaGolin - No I do not, but I certainly will be looking at this now. Thanks so much.

Comment: @MehdiElFadil - I'm afraid before the last few lines is my own testing from yesterday. 'sub_xxx' is my own testing, before the server was sent offline. Thanks!

Comment: Update the user/permissions in the directory where the node.js app is located, so that the user running it gets write access. This will allow the npm-debug.log file to be written, and may give you more information about what is going wrong.

Comment: @MehdiElFadil I set my folder to 777, where does `npm-debug.log` get written to please? Thank you.

Comment: likely in the root directory of your node.js project.

Comment: Does the server keep crashing now? Any different error message in the pm2 logs?

Comment: Every night without fail, nothing in the pm2 logs. I'm at a complete loss here. Unfortunately, it didn't write an `npm-debug.log` file. Nothing in pm2 logs, this was the last line: `0|app      | GET / 200 0.582 ms - 1145`

Comment: Have you tried taking pm2 out of the equation? Run the Express server manually inside `tmux` or `screen` so it will survive a logout.

Comment: @robertklep Thanks for your response. I was told that PM2 was crucial to having an Express server automatically restart when an error occurs. I've never actually heard of `tmux` or `screen`, could you perhaps throw a link my way? The NPM package I found for `tmux` was deprecated. Thank you.

Comment: To track down the cause of your problem it's best to start eliminating things, and pm2 is something that can be easily elimitated. Sorry about not being more clear about `screen/tmux`: those are Linux packages that allow you to "background" a login session (more info on tmux [here](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki)). `sudo apt install tmux` should install it, you'd start it, get a shell window, start Express in it (`node bin/www`), and let it run. Next day, check if it still runs. If not, reattach the login window and see if there's anything that was logged.

Comment: @robertklep Great, thank you. I'll run this tonight and see if the server has gone offline in the morning and let you know :) Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: Have you run `pm2 startup`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should check this [github thread](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/804), it seems like it could help you.

Basically, after few hours, a Nodejs server stop functioning, and the poor nginx can not forward its requests, as the service listening to the forward port is dead. So it triggers a 502 error.

It was all due to a memory leak, that leads to a massive garbage collection, then to the server to crash. Check your memory consumption, you could have some surprises. And try to debug your app code, a piece (dependency) at the time.

**Updated answer:**

So, i will add another branch to my question as it seems it has not helped you so far. 
You could try to get rid of `pm2`, and use `systemd` to manage your app life cycle.

**Create a service file**

```
sudo vim /lib/systemd/system/appname.service
```

this is a simple file i used myself for a random ExpressJS app:

```
[Unit]
Description=YourApp Site Server

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/user/appname/index.js
Restart=always
Environment=PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
Environment=NODE_ENV=production
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/appname

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Note that it will try to restart if it fails somehow `Restart=always`

**Manage it with systemd**

Register the new service with:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Now start your app from systemd with:

```
sudo systemctl start appname
```

from now on you should be able to manage your app life cycle with the usual systemd commands.

You could add stdout and stderr to syslog to understand what you app is doing

```
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
```

Hope it helps more

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for this. I will take a look into this.

Comment: Unfortunately the creator goes on to mention monk JS, which I'm not using.

Comment: ping to @Matt for notification

Answer (score 1):

You cannot say when exactly NodeJS will crash, or will do big GC, or will stun for other reason.

Easiest way to cover such issues is to do health check and restart an app. This should not be an issue when working with cluster.

Please look at [health check module](https://github.com/Telemisis/pm2-health-check) implementation, you may try to use it, or write some simple shell script to do the check